# Laravel Forge DB Mysql Connection via Desktop Client Issue

Tags: database, laravel, forge, table-plus

I have an issue with connecting to my databases via desktop client. I use ssh key to connect to my server via console and I am able to connect to my live server.

But no luck for my database connection. I use TablePlus as my desktop client and I keep getting SSH Error, can't connect to host. That's all I get.

How can I find out what the problem is exactly?

Comment: Maybe their instructions might help figure it out: https://tableplus.com/blog/2019/08/ssh-tunnel-secure-database-connection.html. However it's probably you are either using the incorrect hostname or IP in the SSH server field. Make sure you enter there wat you would use to connect to SSH (`ssh username@server`).

Comment: I changed my login information(switched to forge), now I get, `Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 10060`

Comment: As you suggested, it had to do with host name, I had to to enter ```127.0.0.1``` instead of the server ip. Thanks.